# OpenGL 3.2 2D rendering issues

Tags: c++, opengl, sprite, opengl-3, sdl-2

[rendering artifact http://byte-werx.com/rendering-artifact.png](http://byte-werx.com/rendering-artifact.png)

When I create two sprite batches and attempt to draw twice on the same frame half of my screen (or thereabouts) gets "lost"; this happens regardless of the position of the little campfire sprite.

When rendering in wireframe mode the same results occur so it does not appear that a giant black polygon is getting drawn and overriding the under laying tilemap.

This is the code used to initialize OpenGL:

```
glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glDepthRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glDisable(GL_DITHER);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_CW);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I have uploaded the relevant code here: [download](http://www.byte-werx.com/code.7z)

SDL2 is used for window creation and context management, however I do not use anything else from SDL.

Comment: I' dare say that your projection matrix is wrong, and your plane is skewed towards the front clipping plane... or maybe it is a Z-fighting.... Could you show the code that sets the projection?

Comment: Not sure this is really OpenGL-3.2-specific.

Comment: @rodrigo 

Here is the projection matrix:
m_ProjectionMatrix = glm::ortho(0.0f, 1024.0f, 768.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

Comment: The matrix looks ok. What about the uniform assignment for the shader?

Comment: @rodrigo

    `findUniformLocation("projection");
    int ShaderProgram::findUniformLocation(const char* Name)
{
 auto iter = m_Uniforms.find(Name);
 if(iter == m_Uniforms.end()) {

  //Even if the uniform doesn't exist we want to store the -1 to avoid costly lookups for uniforms that do not exist..
  GLint uniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(m_ProgramId, Name);
  m_Uniforms.insert(std::make_pair(Name, uniformLocation));
  return uniformLocation;
 }
 return iter->second;
}`

That did not format correctly.... Sorry!

Comment: @NateStrandberg: It looks fine. What about the call to `glUniformMatrix4fv()`? If that is also ok, my theory fails badly.

Comment: @rodrigo Here is a pastebin of the entire shader_program.cpp file since stackoverflow does not retain line breaks:

[shader_program.cpp](http://pastebin.com/LvBGv5Gu)

Comment: It looks ok, also. I'm out of ideas!

Comment: @rodrigo All good, thank you for trying :)

It is really odd that it only happens when I try to use two separate sprite batch instances too.

Comment: If you're gonna use modern OpenGL, use it right. (don't use deprecated functions e.g. `glEnableClientState`)

Comment: @CoffeeandCode as I pointed out I am not a graphics programmer, but sarcasm aside I will look into that. Thank you.

Comment: @NateStrandberg It's good to get into the habit is all. Also if you're unsure which functions are deprecated; look at the OpenGL 3.3 reference pages.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I agree completely, still learning OpenGL 3.2 - thanks for the tip and the suggestion for reference pages.

Comment: @NateStrandberg OpenGL 3.2 are <b>very<b> similar, the only difference I've actually dealt with is that in 3.3 all of the deprecated guff is actually removed unless you use a compatibility profile.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Stuff such as gl_Position, correct? Such a shame.. Is there any reason to target above 3.2 for such a simple 2D game do you think?

Comment: @NateStrandberg gl_Position isn't removed or deprecated...

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Okies.

Answer (score -1):

Resolved the issue, I was not unbinding the array/element buffers after calling glDrawElements.

Had to put this after glDrawElements:

```
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```